# Resetting PRAM without a(n) (Apple) keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, imac, nvram

A while back I had an issue with my (2013) iMac not recognizing the keyboard after it was unplugged and re-plugged in.  I had to actually power down the iMac and power it back up before it would recognize the keyboard.  After taking it in to an Apple Store (a 30 mile drive, very inconvenient) they simply reset the PRAM and the problem went away.

Now I find the computer is not recognizing the keyboard again, but this time it doesn't even reset it from a cold boot.  I have tried the keyboard on another iMac and it works there, so I don't think the problem is the keyboard. I would like to try resetting the PRAM again to avoid a trip to the Apple Store if possible, but since the keyboard isn't recognized... well, how do I reset the PRAM?  Is there a way to do it without a keyboard?  Or is there a similar key sequence on a non-Apple keyboard?  I am currently using a Dell keyboard and it works for normal usage, but I don't seem to have all the keys I need to reset the PRAM - I have P and R but where are "command" and "option"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can recreate the NVRAM reset's <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> with a PC keyboard by pressing:

### <sub>[image]</sub> Windows Key + Alt + P + R